# Flask with Azure Active Directory

Tags: python, azure, flask

I have deployed a flask application on azure as an App Service and I implemented the Azure Active Directory authentication. Everything works nice as when I try to open the webapp it redirects me to the Microsoft Sign On, but I cannot figure out how to retrieve the user's information from the current session. Is there a way from python to retrieve the current user logged through Azure AD? In the documentation I could not find any information about that..

Answer (score 0):

You can call the Microsoft Graph API using the AAD access token set in the response header, [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-authentication-oauth-tokens):

```
import requests

accessToken = request.headers.get('X-MS-TOKEN-AAD-ACCESS-TOKEN')

headers = {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer {0}'.format(accessToken),
    'User-Agent': 'MyAgentName/1.0'}

r = requests.get(
    'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me',
    headers=headers)

user_name =  r.json()['displayName']
print(user_name)
```

Comment: thank you so much for your reply! Do you eventually know how could I do this thing testable locally? I have tried so many different stuff with no success (copying the access token from another session, using msal.. ), since I implemented the easy auth directly from azure it is difficult to retrieve an access token from the app running locally and yet i cannot use an access token copied from another session

Comment: I think I had a environment switch... Production used the token injected in the headers. But during local development I had to use token retrieved using the MSAL library (actually think it was ADAL at the time...).

Comment: thank you so much, yes after some temptatives yesterday I managed to do the same, I used MSAL to get a token during local testing with the interactive token acquire while in prod I use the easy auth, thank you so much! (had some troubles with the redirect uri but managed to solve it, it really gave me headache)